# Why am i getting this gltf file node found error

Tags: html, express

I'm trying to load a GLTF file and I am receiving this error: I don't know why it can't locate and open the file?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bbMoy.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8aAMZ.png)

html code:-

```
<html>
  <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
  <!-- we import arjs version without NFT but with marker + location based support -->
  <!-- <script src="https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/aframe/build/aframe-ar.js"></script> -->
  <body style="margin: 0px; overflow: hidden">
    <a-scene>
      <a-assets>
        <a-asset-items id="hello" src="hello.gltf"> </a-asset-items>
      </a-assets>
      <a-entity gltf-model="#hello"></a-entity>

      <!-- <a-entity camera></a-entity> -->
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>



 app.js for server: -
 
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

console.log(path.join(__dirname, '/index.html'));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/index.html'));
});


app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```